# Block PUBG completely from working in Android mobile

Tags: applications, internet, parental-control

My relative's child is addicted to PUBG. She needs to block PUBG completely. Is there a way to block it from getting connected to PUBG servers, or crashing the app every time it opens?

Please note: My relative is not very tech-savvy. The simpler method, the more helpful it would be.

Comment: What about just forfeiting the phone?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Block-Apps-on-Android

Comment: Cannot leave him without phone as we both travel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the Parental Control in the PlayStore or simply remove the Network access in the App Settings.

If possible, ask them to spend some time with that kid. This addiction is not a serious issue if you can spend some good time with kid.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods that actually work for me.

1. Lock the game/app with an app or from the android if you have that function.
2. Go to Google Play-->Settings--->Parental controls. Once opened, you will be able to set up the restrictions you want.
3. Restrict the internet access to the game. You can do it from your system if you have this feature. Otherwise, just get an application from Google Play, search for "app internet restriction" for example.